# The implements bind a collection of object to DataGrid in two-ways

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to implement a two-ways binding between `DataGrid` and `Collection`.
What I want is delete a item in my `Collection` will automatically cause the `DataGrid` items been removing, Is there any possibility to make it ?

What I done so far is :

The code for item of my Collection.

```
    [XmlRoot("configitem")]
    public class ConfigItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool bDelete = false;
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool ToBeDelete {
            get
            {
                return bDelete;
            }
            set
            {
                bDelete = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ToBeDelete");
            }
        }

        [XmlAttribute("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The XAML code is :

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox Content="All" x:Name="chkAll" Click="chkAll_Click" />
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkSelect" IsChecked="{Binding ToBeDelete, 
              Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Margin="15 2 0 0" Click="chkSelect_Click" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Name}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ConfigName"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Value}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ConfigValue"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="6*" Binding="{Binding Description}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Description"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

[image]

When I clicked the check box in first column. 
The `PropertyChanged` event will be fired. This will make the value change to the collection item.And It worked.

When I click delete button. I try to delete the specified items from the current binding collection. The collection item are deleted. But Why the grid row for them weren't removed?

```
public void Delete()
{
    List<ConfigItem> TobeRemovedList = configs.Where(x => x.ToBeDelete.Equals(true)).ToList();
    TobeRemovedList.ForEach(x => configs.Remove(x));
}
```

Should I need to call bind again in delete button so that the DataGrid know the collection changed?

If what I did is far away from the best practice. Please kindly tell me how. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You need to use `ObservableCollection<T>` as opposed to `List<T>` because latter doesn't supports change notifications. So data binding engine will not know that  your list has changed and thus it can't update the `DataGrid`.

Also you need to keep the `ObservableCollection<T>` as a field, not as a local variable creating new again and again.

Comment: Thanks your kind review and answer. I got it . What I need to do is wrap my collection as a field of new Class. And bind the new Class instance and set right field path to the DataGrid. Right ? Because I already implement the property changed notifications although I am not using `ObservableCollection<T>`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes exactly, I can see you're using something named `configs`, instead of that you need to bind the `DataGrid` with `ObservableCollection`. Typically you expose a property of type `ObservableCollection` and bind it to  `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. You can find lots of examples in SO or in google. If you need more help I'm happy to help.

Comment: It already help me lot.I will follow the direction you show to me. Thanks your kind help!

Comment: `Also you need to keep the ObservableCollection<T> as a field, not as a local variable creating new again and again.` In my test. This is very important. the ObservableCollection should be keep the same instance in the window otherwise will cause the binding failure. Thanks.